# Multiple consumer group and destination for a single channel in bindings

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

So I am trying to have a single `function` for `multiple topic destinations` and `consumer groups`. However I am stuck with the syntax. I am trying to achieve the below, but not sure if that's possible and if it is then what will be the syntax in the `application.yml`

```
function : handleEvent

topics: topicAEvent, topicBEvent, topicCEvent
consumer group : AEventConsumergroup, BEventConsumergroup, CEventConsumerGroup
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
 cloud:
  function:
   definition: handleEvent;
  stream:
   kafka:
    bindings:
     handleEvent-in-0:
      group: AEventConsumergroup, BEventConsumergroup, CEventConsumerGroup
      destination: topicAEvent, topicBEvent, topicCEvent
```

Is there a way to have a single function that can provide `Consumer Bean for multiple kafka topics and consumer groups?`

Comment: You should make unique bindings for each group and topic

Comment: @OneCricketeer, thanks for the comment. But is there any benefit to that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but `group` and `destination` can only take one value in the config, I believe. You can use one Kafka consumer group with multiple topics being consumed, though. Otherwise, if you want to loop through a list of entries, you'll need to programmatically build the stream binder